# Password protect a simple web site

Tags: html, security, passwords

I've got an HTML-only website (with a bit of inconsequential javascript).  The static pages are generated from a photo-blogging program that I created.  There are hundreds of pages and thousands of pictures.

I'm considering adding very basic security to the site (as a marginal impediment to someone who's casually attempting to access the site).  I could probably live with a single password for everyone, although I suppose multiple username/password combos wouldn't hurt.  (I don't want this this to become an administrative hassle.)

Doing a quick search, I've discovered that there are myriad ways to implement authentication, but most seem to be overkill for my needs.  Because so many people disable javascript, I don't want to use client-side authentication.  The site is hosted with GoDaddy on a Windows server, so I have some control over IIS settings.  I've also got access to ASP.NET, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.

Since I generate the pages, it's no big deal to change them all to a new standard approach.  Any suggestions for a simple approach?

Comment: .htaccess is your friend... too bad you are on Windows.

Comment: I noticed a few references to htaccess in my searches.  I don't know how it compares to directory security in IIS.  My initial impression is that htaccess is more flexible, but I'm not sure that it would be a limitation in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like basic HTTP authentication would fit the job perfectly.

Here's the [MSDN article on setting up HTTP Basic Authentication on IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/abbca505-6f63-4267-aac1-1ea89d861eb4.mspx?mfr=true).

(Though sadly, it's a lot more annoying to set up on IIS than it would be on Apache.)

Comment: At first gland that looks like it's dependent on Windows security, with local users, groups, etc.  Will this be applicable to an Internet wide site?  I'm also concerned that I won't have that much control over IIS' settings in my GoDaddy hosting account.